# How to add ManyToMany field with 'through' relation to fixtures?

Tags: django, django-models, pytest, fixtures, pytest-django

In tests (fixtures) I want to add field with ManyToMany field with 'through' relation, i.e

```
my_field = models.ManyToManyField(SomeModel, through=AnotherModel).
```

Tried to add like regular ManyToManyField like:

```
object.my_field.add(my_field)
```

but it gives me this warning message: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NywlB.png)

Also, tried this:

```
object.my_field.add(my_field, through_defaults=AnotherModel)
```

also didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply construct an `AnotherModel` object, so:

```
AnotherModel.objects.create(firstmodel=object, somemodel=myfield)
```

If the `AnotherModel` contains extra fields that have no default value, you will need to specify these as well.

Or you can make use of [**`.add(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) where the `through_defaults` should contain a **dictionary** with values to pass to the `AnotherModel`:

```
object.my_field.add(my_field, through_defaults={'field1': 14, 'field2': 25})
```

See the [*Extra fields on many-to-many relationships* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for more information about the `through_defaults`. This contains an example like:

> ```
> beatles.members.set([john, paul, ringo, george], through_defaults={'date_joined': date(1960, 8, 1)})
> ```

In this example the `members` of the `beatles` object is a `ManyToManyField` with an intermediate model, and here we fill in `date(1960, 8, 1)` as value for `date_joined` in that model.

Comment: @DinaNasyrkhan: well a `ManyToManyField` is nothing more than just a model that has two `ForeignKey`s to the models it links. If you do not specify a `through` model yourself, Django automatically creates one. Behind the curtains if you make use of `.add()`, it will create an `AnotherModel`, so there is indeed not much use of adding an extra fixture.

Comment: look
I have this:
restaurant.contract.add(contract, through_defaults=restaurant_contract), here restaurant_contract is another fixture(with AnotherModel.objects.create(firstmodel=object, somemodel=myfield)). 
This still gives me an error. Also tried: restaurant.contract.add(contract, through_defaults={'restaurant'=restaurant, 'contract'=contract}), still doesnt work

Comment: Also, if I didn't add extra fileld and leave like restaurant.contract.add(contract) it says that it is not correct(warning message above). Is there any solutions?

Comment: @DinaNasyrkhan: well I can not find that error message in the [implementation of `.add(..)`]( https://github.com/django/django/blob/3ab5235d1dc94f7c8fe37a98c4e2c2337a5e5548/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L1027), perhaps you used some signals, other plugins, etc. that prevent this. But I manage to reproduce adding relation objects.

Comment: @DinaNasyrkhan: do you by any chance use an old version of Django? Prior to 2.2 using `.add(..)` for m2m fields with a `through` model was not possible iirc.

Comment: yeap, django version is 2.2.8(
Is there any other solutions, except updating django? :D